# sum of a subset of rows in a data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a little problem...let's say I have a data.table with one numerical column like:

```
  NR
  1
  2
  3
  5
  7 
  10
  1
```

I want to create a new column which is computed in this way:
in row j I want the sum of NR in the rows j, j+1, j+2. So I want this result:

```
  NR    NEW_NR
  1     6
  2     10
  3     15
  5     22
  7     18
  10    11
  1     1
```

Could anyone help me pls?

Comment: have a look at `shift` or rolling sum functions from other packages.

Comment: @mt1022 thank you, maybe this is what I need!

Comment: `dt[, S := Reduce(\`+\`, shift(NR, 0:2, type = "lead"))]`

Comment: @Jimbou you are right, I'll delete asap the question!